# Como agregar elementos dinamicamente a un formulario c# desde una clase

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

siendo mas detallista, estoy tratando de agregar (por el momento) unos botones a un formulario de c#, mi dilema es que no tengo la menor idea de como agregar estos elementos desde la clase por defecto que tiene todos los formularios de c#, y los ejemplos que he visto no me han funcionado.

Lo que tengo por el momento es un fallido intento con AddOwnedForm.

```
this.productByUserList = myListProducts;
Point newLoc = new Point(5, 5); // Set whatever you want for initial location
//Se recorre la lista de elementos que quiero agregar, se define una posición por defecto y aunque los botones se agregan no logro que me muestre texto o agregarle estilos propios desde c#
foreach (productByUserObject productOfUser in this.productByUserList)
{
   //Añadir elementos 
   Button buttonTest = new Button();
   buttonTest.Size = new Size(10, 50);
   buttonTest.Location = newLoc;
   buttonTest.Text = productOfUser.name;
   newLoc.Offset(0, buttonTest.Height + 5);
   Controls.Add(buttonTest);
}
```

A lo que me refiero como clase por defecto es a

```
// a la clase que se crea junto con el formulario
public partial class productByUserForm : Form
{}
```

Quedo atento a nuevas actualizaciones que me pidan

Comment: podrias publicar el codigo que estas utilizando ?

Comment: cual es la clase que tiene por defecto todos los formularios ? te refieres a la clase Form

Comment: @LeandroTuttini claro, dame unos minutos ya actualizo la pregunta, por clase por defecto me refiero a la clase que una vez creado los formularios la clase se crea con ella, adjuntare ejemplo en la pregunta.

Comment: te falto definir el contexto de ese codigo, entiendo esta dentro del metodo que llamas AddOwnedForm(), pero este lo invocas desde el Load o desde el Click de algun boton

Comment: Se define como constructor, el código que subí ya no trabaja con la función addOwnedForm, ya pude crear los botones dinamicamente pero salen del formulario, conoces alguna forma para hacerlo o debería abrir otra pregunta, que me recomiendas?

Comment: podrias poner los botones dentro de un Panel y habilitar el scroll, o sino agregar logica que valide las dimensiones y cuando detectes supera cierto valor, entonces lo reinicias y sumas al a la otra, asi aparecera al costado

Comment: Voy a intentar con los paneles, aunque aquí surge otra pregunta, los eventos click de los botones creados, como los puedo definir, ya que necesito que al dar click me envié un valor a una función en especifico, como puedo hacer esto en el evento?

Comment: extendi la respuesta agregando un ejemplo de como adjuntas un evento de forma dinamica

Comment: Listo, muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El contexto del codigo podria ser de esta forma

```
public partial class productByUserForm : Form
{

    public void productByUserForm_Load()
    {
        AddOwnedForm();
    }

    private void AddOwnedForm()
    {
        this.productByUserList = myListProducts;
        Point newLoc = new Point(5, 5); 

        foreach (productByUserObject productOfUser in this.productByUserList)
        {
           Button buttonTest = new Button();
           buttonTest.Size = new Size(10, 50);
           buttonTest.Location = newLoc;
           buttonTest.Text = productOfUser.name;
           newLoc.Offset(0, buttonTest.Height + 5);
           this.Controls.Add(buttonTest);
        }
    }

}
```

como veras dentro del metodo `AddOwnedForm()` se define este codigo el cual es invocado desde el Load del form, pero podrias hacerlo desde el click de un boton, es indistinto pero tiene que ser desde algun evento

Tambien si quieres podrias hacerlo desde el constructor del form, pero recuerda poner la llamada despues del `InitializeComponent()`

Para trabajar con el evento del boton simplemente defines

```
buttonTest.Click += buttonTest_Click;
```

y a nivel del form

```
public void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

   Button buttonTest = (Button)sender;

   //resto codigo

}
```

podras conocer que boton lanzo el evento evaluando el `sender`